# Program type already present after updating Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting same error and I am using `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`, can anyone help me about this, I just update latest firebase library like firebase database 17.0.4 to 17.1.2, please help me for this, thank you

My old libraries were

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
```

And my latest libraries are

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error
i just put same app version of libreary for firebase like `auth`, `starage` ets like below,

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
```